# How to pass this configuration from Nginx to Apache2?

Tags: nginx, apache2

Hello i would like to pass all of this config to apache2, i'am just not sure how to do it i actually need every line of nginx to apache2? if someone could spare two minutes to write.

```
server {
  server_name app.my.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```